# Separating a string into smaller strings

Tags: c, string

I have the following string `abcd1234` and I want to find a way to break this string into two different strings, `abcd` and `1234`. I have tried the following code:

```
char buf[100],*str1,*str2;
int x;
fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
str1=strtok(buf,"0123456789 \t\n");
str2=strtok(NULL," \n\t\0");
puts(str1);
puts(str2);
x=atoi(str2);
printf("x=%d", x);
```

but output is `abcd 234`. And if I try it with one letter and one number, e.g `a2` I take only e on output and `x` is 0.

Comment: What is the criteria of breaking that you want?

Comment: You can't use strtok unless there is some sort of delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) of `strtok()`

> Each call to strtok() returns a pointer to a null-terminated string containing the next token. **This string does not include the delimiting byte.** [...]

So, while using `"0123456789 \t\n"` as the delimiter for the first time, `1` will be treated as the actual delimiter and will not be considered in the subsequent parsing.

You may want to use [`strcspn()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcspn) and/or [`strpbrk()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strpbrk) to find out the index for the required sub-strings and parse accordingly.

Comment: `strpbrk(input, "0123456789");` will be inefficient though, since `strpbrk` can't know that it is looking for numbers. A manual solution with `isdigit` will be much more effective.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

size_t extract(const char **sp, char *out, int (*test)(int ch));

int main(void){
    char buf[100], str1[100], str2[100];
    int x;
    const char *p = buf;
    //size_t len;

    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
    while(*p){
        if(isalpha((unsigned char)*p)){
            extract(&p, str1, isalpha);
            puts(str1);
        } else if(isdigit((unsigned char)*p)){
            extract(&p, str2, isdigit);
            x = atoi(str2);
            printf("%s, x=%d\n", str2, x);
        } else {
            ++p;//skip one char
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

size_t extract(const char **sp, char *out, int (*test)(int ch)){
    const char *p = *sp;
    while(*p && test((unsigned char)*p)){
        *out++ = *p++;
    }
    *out = '\0';
    size_t len = p - *sp;
    *sp = p;
    return len;
}
```

Comment: Here `size_t len = p - *sp;` you have ...`conversion to ‘size_t’ from ‘long int’ may change the sign of the result`

Comment: @Michi Negative results does not occur.

Comment: I'm sure about that, may point was  that warning only :D...any way nice approach.

Comment: Any way the OP didn't mentioned what should be the output when `hallo12-3` is present, which means that his 100% sure that the string does contain letters and numbers

Comment: Yes it is unclear. but negative number is not considered in OP's exsample code.

Comment: consider there are no negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

- Try below code.Hope this will help you.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <ctype.h>
  int main()
  {
     char string[]="abcd1234";
     char digitStr[10];
     char charStr[10];
     int i,j = 0,k = 0;

     for(i=0;string[i];i++)
     {
          if(isdigit(string[i]))
          {
                  charStr[j++]=string[i];
          }
          else
          {
                  digitStr[k++]=string[i];
          }
     }
     charStr[j] = '\0';
     digitStr[k] = '\0';
     printf("%s %s\n",digitStr,charStr);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

*I realize I'm very late on this one, but this is for if anyone has a similar case*

Assuming all input strings are like your example, this method will work.

```C
char buf[100];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
if (buf[strlen(buf) - 1] == '\n')
    buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';
int x = atoi(strpbrk(buf, "0123456789"));
char letters[number - buf + 1];
memcpy(letters, sizeof(letters) - 1, buf);
letters[sizeof(letters) - 1] = '\0';
//letters is the word
//x is the number as an int, not a string
```

• Note the `if` statement after the `fgets`. This checks that the newline character was read by fgets, and turns it into a NUL character. (essentially truncating the string).
• As for `strpbrk()`, that's just a function that returns a pointer to the first occurence of any character in the second string inside the first string. I use it here to find the start of the digit sequence.
• I would also drop the `atoi()` for `strtol()` for safety.
• The `letters[]` array size is the return of `strpbrk()` (the address of the first number), minus the start of the array (giving the length of the letter string in bytes), plus one for the NUL character I add later.